# How can I understand some of the layers in my Shiny application?

Tags: css, shiny, background-color, shinydashboard

I managed to change the background color of the sidebarpanel, but only partially. Is it possible to control the background color of the part in frame 1 to make it similar to the rest of the sidebarpanel in blue. I would also like to change the background color of the part in frame 2. I tried to control the background color of fillPage or fluidRow by css selector. I tried these

```
fillPage(id="fillPage_hospit")
fillPage(div(id="fillPage_hospit"))
```

and in the css:

```
#fillPage_hospit{
   background-color: yellow;
   color:darkblue;
        }
```

Nothing works. I don't even know which layer these parts correspond to.I'm lost, please help me.
[image]

Below my user interface codes :

```
ui <- dashboardPage(
  # skin="black",
                  
                    dashboardHeader(
                      # title = HTML(
                      #   "<div style='font-size: 20px;
                      #   font-family: Pacifico, cursive;
                      #   font-weight: bold;
                      #   font-style: italic;
                      #   color: red;
                      #   margin-left: 0px;'>TRAJECTOIRE-PATIENTS</div>"
                      # ),
                      titleWidth = 300,
                      title = "TRAJECTOIRE-PATIENTS"
                    ),
                    dashboardSidebar(width = 250,
                                     sidebarMenu(
                                       menuItem( "Analyse de la concurrence",
                                                 menuSubItem("Cartographie sur les hopitaux", tabName = "StatHopital"),
                                                 menuSubItem("Cartographie sur les communes",tabName = "StatCommune"),
                                                 
                                                 div(
                                                   id="all_select",
                                                   class="class_slct",
                                                   
                                                   style="font-size:12px;",
                                                     
                                                     
                                                     
                                                     selectInput("LibGHM", 
                                                                 label = div(style = "display: flex; align-items: center;",
                                                                             HTML(paste0('<i class="fas fa-user-md" style="color: white; margin-right: 5px;" title="Doctor"></i>')),
                                                                             "Spécialités"),
                                                                 choices = c("Total",levels(as.factor(sejdig$Libéllé.CHIC))),
                                                                 selected="Total"
                                                     ),
                                                     
                                                     
                                                     uiOutput("ui"),
                                                     
                                                     
                                                     
                                                     selectInput("Urgence", 
                                                                 label = div(style = "display: flex; align-items: center;",
                                                                             HTML(paste0('<i class="fas fa-ambulance" style="color: white; margin-right: 5px;" title="Ambulance"></i>')),
                                                                             "Urgence"),
                                                                 choices = c("Total",levels(as.factor(sejdig$Urgence))),
                                                                 selected="Total"
                                                     ),
                                                     
                                                     
                                                     selectInput("Majorite", 
                                                                 label = div(style = "display: flex; align-items: center;",
                                                                             HTML(paste0('<i class="fas fa-user" style="color: white; margin-right: 10px;" title="Doctor"></i>')),
                                                                             HTML(paste0('<i class="fas fa-child" style="color: white; margin-right: 5px;" title="Child"></i>')),
                                                                             "Majorité"),
                                                                 choices = c("Total",levels(as.factor(sejdig$Majorite))),
                                                                 selected="Total"
                                                     ),
                                                     
                                                     div(id="zone",
                                                         class="my_clase",
                                                       selectInput(inputId = "Zone",
                                                                 label=div(style = "display: flex; align-items: center;",
                                                                           HTML(paste0('<i class="fas fa-bullseye" style="color: white; margin-right: 5px;" title="Child"></i>')),
                                                                           "Seuil de Zone de récrutement"),
                                                                 choices = c("Ensemble des patients","Zone de recrutement","Zone d'attraction"),
                                                                 selected="Zone de recrutement")),
                                                     
                                                     
                                                     selectInput(inputId ="indicateur",div(style = "display: flex; align-items: center;",
                                                                                           HTML(paste0('<i class="fas fa-chart-line" style="color: white; margin-right: 5px;" title=""></i>')),
                                                                                           "Indicateurs"),
                                                                 choices = c("Nombre de patients"="nb_patient_tot",
                                                                             "Nombre de patients rapporté à la population"="nb_patient_pop")))
                                                 
                                                 
                                                 
                                       )
                                       
                                       
                                       
                                       
                                       
                                       
                                       
                                     )
                    )
  ,
  dashboardBody(
    
     tags$style(type = "text/css",
               "html, body {width:100%;height:100%}",

               ".leaflet .legend {
                                         font-size: 8px;
                                       line-height: 6px;}",

               ".leaflet .legend i{
                                       width: 8px;
                                       height: 8px;
                                       }"
    ),
    
    tags$style(HTML('
        
        /* logo */
        .skin-blue .main-header .logo {
                              background-color: #483d8b;
                              color: red;
                              font-weight: bold;
                              margin-left: 0px;
                              font-family: Pacifico, cursive;
                              font-style: italic;
                              }

        /* logo when hovered 
        .skin-blue .main-header .logo:hover {
                              background-color: #483d8b;
                              }*/

        /* navbar (rest of the header) */
        .skin-blue .main-header .navbar {
                              background-color: #483d8b;
                              }        

        /* main sidebar */
        .skin-blue .main-sidebar {
                              background-color: #483d8b;
                              }

        /* active selected tab in the sidebarmenu */
        .skin-blue .main-sidebar .sidebar .sidebar-menu .active {
                              background-color: #483d8b;
                              }

        /* other links in the sidebarmenu 
        .skin-blue .main-sidebar .sidebar .sidebar-menu a{
                              background-color: green;
                              color: #000000;
                              }*/
                              
        .skin-blue .main-body {
                        background-color:yellow;
                          }


        /* other links in the sidebarmenu when hovered 
         .skin-blue .main-sidebar .sidebar .sidebar-menu a:hover{
                              background-color: #ff69b4;}*/
                              
        #zone .selectize-dropdown-content > .option {
   background-color: grey;
        }
        
         #fillPage_hospit{
   background-color: yellow;
   color:darkblue;
        }
        
        
        
         #all_select .selectize-dropdown-content > .option {
   background-color: lightgrey;
         }
        
 .bg-black {
    background-color: red !important;
    height: 55px;
    line-height:55px;

}


.sidebar {
     height:100vh;
     overflow-y:auto 
}

 .nav-tabs-custom > .nav-tabs > li.active {
     border-top-color:#616365 
}
      
        /* toggle button when hovered  */                    
         .skin-blue .main-header .navbar .sidebar-toggle:hover{
                              background-color: #ff69b4;
                              }
 
                              
                              ')),
    
    
    
    tabItems(

      tabItem(
        tabName = "StatHopital",
          #style="font-size:11px;width: 1200px; height: 700px",
             tags$style(type = "text/css", "#StatHopital {height: calc(100vh - 80px) !important;}"),
            
                                    
                                    # EMPTY FILL ROW HOSPITAL SELECTION
                                    fillPage(
                                      div(id="fillPage_hospit")),
                                      ## FIRST FILL ROW
                                      
                                      fluidRow(
                                        column(selectInput(inputId = "Hopital1",choices = c(listeHop),
                                                             label = "Choisir l'hôpital 1",width = "75%"),
                                               style = "display: flex; justify-content: center; color:darkblue; 
                                               background-color:pink;
                                               height:50%;",
                                               width = 6),
                                        column(selectInput(inputId = "Hopital2",choices = rev(c(listeHop)),
                                                             label = "Choisir l'hôpital 2",width = "75%"),
                                               style = "display: flex; justify-content: center;
                                               display: flex; justify-content: center; color:darkblue; 
                                               background-color:pink;",
                                                 width = 6), 
                                        heigth="2%"
                                        )
                                      ,
                                      

                                      # FILL ROW WITH GRAPH
                                      fluidRow(tabsetPanel(id="hopital_tabset",
                                      tabPanel("Zone de recrutement",
                                               fluidRow(
                                                 fillPage(
                                                   tags$style(type = "text/css", "#ZoneHop1 {height: calc(90vh - 80px) !important;}"),
                                                   column(leafletOutput("ZoneHop1",height = 1000,width = "100%"),
                                                        width=6)),
                                                 fillPage(
                                                   tags$style(type = "text/css", "#ZoneHop2 {height: calc(90vh - 80px) !important;}"),
                                                   column(leafletOutput("ZoneHop2",height = 1000,width = "100%"),
                                                      width=6)
                                                   )
                                               )
                                      ),
                                   
                                      
                                      tabPanel("Part de marché",
                                               fluidRow(
                                                 fillPage(
                                                   tags$style(type = "text/css", "#MktShareZ1 {height: calc(90vh - 80px) !important;}"),
                                                   column(leafletOutput("MktShareZ1"),
                                                          width=6)),
                                                 fillPage(
                                                   tags$style(type = "text/css", "#MktShareZ2 {height: calc(90vh - 80px) !important;}"),
                                                   column(leafletOutput("MktShareZ2"),
                                                          width=6)
                                                 )
                                               )
                                      ),
                                      
                                      
                                      
                                      
                                      tabPanel("Concurrence", 
                                               fillPage(
                                                 tags$style(type = "text/css", "#Comp1 {height: calc(90vh - 80px) !important;}"),
                                                 leafletOutput("Comp1",height = "100%",width = "100%"))
                                               )
                                      ),height="100%"
                                      )
                                      )
        ),

      tabItem(
        tabName = "StatCommune",div(style="font-size:11px;",

                                    fluidRow(box(selectInput(inputId = "Commune",choices = c(levels(as.factor(LibCom$libgeo_cp))),
                                                             label = "Choisir la commune"),
                                                 width = 6,height = 70,
                                                 solidHeader = TRUE)),
                                    fluidRow( tabsetPanel(
                                      tabPanel("Nombre de séjours par communes",
                                               fillPage(
                                                 tags$style(type = "text/css", "#sejourCom {height: calc(90vh - 80px) !important;}"),
                                                 leafletOutput("sejourCom", height="100%", width="100%")
                                                 )
                                      ),
                                      tabPanel("Concurrence au sein de la commune",
                                               fillPage(
                                                 tags$style(type = "text/css", "#HHI_IDF {height: calc(90vh - 80px) !important;}"),
                                                 leafletOutput("HHI_IDF", height="100%", width="100%")
                                                 )
                                      ),
                                      tabPanel("Flux des communes vers les hopitaux",
                                               fillPage(
                                                 tags$style(type = "text/css", "#Commune2 {height: calc(90vh - 80px) !important;}"),
                                                 leafletOutput ("Commune2", height="100%", width="100%")
                                                 )
                                               )
                                      # ,
                                      # tabPanel("Flux des communes vers les hopitaux",
                                      #          dataTableOutput ("Commune3"))
                                    ))
        ))
    )



    )
)
```

Comment: Your code snippet is full of irrelevant details but misses the important parts. First, add the libraries which are needed to the beginning. Second, make the code self-contained and reproducible for us by providing all necessary parts, e.g. `sejdig` or `listeHop` or by deleting these parts. Finally, create a minimal example by deleting everything which is not needed for answering your question.